# .NET 4.0 / MVC 3 - Where is System.Web.Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've downloaded the latest [Who can help me?](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/) s#arp arcitecture app from codeplex. This is a VS 2008 / MVC 2 solution, and I have VS 2010 / MVC 3 - no probs I thought, I will convert it.

However, my web projects are complaining about a missing assembly System.Web.Mvc, which does not seem to exist anywhere on my system. I haven't been able to find anything to the contrary that this assembly has been superseded.

Any ideas?

Comment: What fails, the who can help me conversion or your projects using the converted dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed ASP.NET MVC3 ?

When you install visual studio 2010, it's shipped with MVC2, so you still need to install MVC3.

After installing MVC3 you should have System.Web.Mvc into your GAC.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have MVC2 and its here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies

Comment: For me C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies. Problem is this isnt in the GAC. The one in the gac is v2, the new one is v3,and anyway neither were appearing under the .NET tab of add reference, so i've browsed to this location.